# Apply filter to casted column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to apply a filter to a column I've casted as DATE, as the example below:

```
select A, B, CAST(C as DATE) as D, E from MY_TABLE where D>'2018-12-12'
```

Which doesn't work. I get the error: "Invalid column name 'D'."
I've also tried:

```
select A, B, CAST(C as DATE) as D, E from MY_TABLE where C>'2018-12-12'
```

Getting the same error. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Do us a favor and properly tag which database you are using?

Comment: Did you try it without the as?

Comment: @Kars Just did, got the same error

Comment: @JerryM. I'm sorry, I don't think I get what you mean

Comment: Are you using Oracle? SQL Server? Access? Each of these have different variants of SQL.

Comment: @JerryM. Got it. It's an SQL Server

Comment: What is the error you get for: `select A, B, CAST(C as DATE) as D, E from MY_TABLE where C>'2018-12-12'`? It can't be `Invalid column name 'D'`.

Comment: @forpas Invalid column name 'C'

Comment: Then what is C?

Comment: @forpas If I get you question, I believe it is the original date column, which i'm trying to get casted as DATE

Comment: If `C` is a column of the table `MY_TABLE` it is not possible that you get `Invalid column name 'C'` for `select A, B, CAST(C as DATE) as D, E from MY_TABLE where C>'2018-12-12'`

Comment: @forpas I've just double checked, but that's exactly the error message I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if `C` is already a date/time type, you can simply do:

```
select A, B, CAST(C as DATE) as D, E
from MY_TABLE 
where C > DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2018-12-12')
```

If not, you can use a lateral join, which in SQL Server uses the `APPLY` keyword:

```
select A, B, v.D, E
from MY_TABLE t cross apply
     (values (CAST(C as DATE))) v(D)
where v.D > '2018-12-12';
```

If `C` is a string, I strongly recommend `TRY_CAST()` or fixing the data in-place.

Comment: I've tried both your suggestions. The first didn't work (got the same error), but the second worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Gaduks . . . Glad the second one helped.  I don't see how the first one could return an invalid reference to `D`, because it is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: It returns "invalid column name C". I meant same error in the sense that it does not recognise the filter column. I'm sorry for the ambiguity